# How to use val.py to calculate mAP on custom testing dataset of YOLOv5?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, yolov5

I am trying to calucate mAP on my testing dataset using this:

```
!python val.py  --task test
```

I am using a custom `data.yaml` file. But I don't know how to point to that `data.yaml`. And when I use the following code:

```
val.py --data= /content/data.yaml --task test
```

The model outputs an `invalid argument` error. Also by default it is trying to calculate mAP on `coco.yaml`.

Answer (score 1):

You shall use val instead of test value for task parameter like as below.

python val.py --weights {{model}} --data data.yaml --task val